# Spyder 4.1.2 (Python 3.8) Blank Screen

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

**Issue:** When I open Spyder in the (base) environment using `spyder` it opens Spyder (Python 3.7) no issues. When I `activate myenv` and open `spyder` the Spyder opens in a blank screen and if I click anywhere it hangs and says not responding.

See image:
[image: blank screen spyder python]

Any ideas what the problem might be? I have tried `conda update --all`

**How to recreate the error:** Open Anaconda Command Prompt:

```
conda create --name myenv
activate myenv
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
conda install spyder
conda update --all
spyder
```

I have also tried installing jupyter lab and spyder using the Anaconda Navigator.

**My system:**

Dell XPS-15, 64-bit running Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Support for Python 3.8 on Windows will come in our 4.1.3 version, to be released the first week of May 2020.

Comment: Thanks for this Carlos, I rolled back to Python 3.7 and Spyder launches fine now. Will wait for 4.1.3

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps in command prompt: `conda install qt=5.6 pyqt=5.6 sip=4.18`

Comment: No luck. This is the error returned:
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
Examining @/win-64::__cuda==10.2=0:  20%|█████▏                    | 1/5 [00:00<00:00, 15.19it/s]/failed                                                         \

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment

Specifications:

  - pyqt=5.6 -> python=3.4
  - pyqt=5.6 -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8

Comment: here is someone with a similar issue: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/6940 , it worked when unplugging the external screen from the laptop, try so if you have an external screen to it.

Comment: I don't have an external screen :/